# How to send notification to android phone from Bluetooth Low Energy beacon?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to send a notification to an Android phone from a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) beacon.

I have already created a simple app and fetched my BLE device's UUID on my Android phone. I now want to receive a notification containing my BLE device's UUID from the beacon when I enable the Bluetooth on my phone.

Here is the code in which I'm getting the UUID of the beacon. How do I send the beacon's UUID to the user when they turn on their phone's Bluetooth?

```
package com.sobag.beaconplayground;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // members
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";

    private BluetoothManager btManager;
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
    private Handler scanHandler = new Handler();
    private int scan_interval_ms = 5000;
    private boolean isScanning = false;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // default stuff...
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // init BLE
        btManager = (BluetoothManager)getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        btAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();

        scanHandler.post(scanRunnable);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // public usage
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private Runnable scanRunnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (isScanning)
            {
                if (btAdapter != null)
                {
                    btAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (btAdapter != null)
                {
                    btAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
                }
            }

            isScanning = !isScanning;

            scanHandler.postDelayed(this, scan_interval_ms);
        }
    };

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Inner classes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord)
        {
            int startByte = 2;
            boolean patternFound = false;
            while (startByte <= 5)
            {
                if (    ((int) scanRecord[startByte + 2] & 0xff) == 0x02 && //Identifies an iBeacon
                        ((int) scanRecord[startByte + 3] & 0xff) == 0x15)
                { //Identifies correct data length
                    patternFound = true;
                    break;
                }
                startByte++;
            }

            if (patternFound)
            {
                //Convert to hex String
                byte[] uuidBytes = new byte[16];
                System.arraycopy(scanRecord, startByte + 4, uuidBytes, 0, 16);
                String hexString = bytesToHex(uuidBytes);

                //UUID detection
                String uuid =  hexString.substring(0,8) + "-" +
                        hexString.substring(8,12) + "-" +
                        hexString.substring(12,16) + "-" +
                        hexString.substring(16,20) + "-" +
                        hexString.substring(20,32);

                // major
                final int major = (scanRecord[startByte + 20] & 0xff) * 0x100 + (scanRecord[startByte + 21] & 0xff);

                // minor
                final int minor = (scanRecord[startByte + 22] & 0xff) * 0x100 + (scanRecord[startByte + 23] & 0xff);

                Log.i(LOG_TAG,"UUID: " +uuid + "\\nmajor: " +major +"\\nminor" +minor);
            }

        }
    };

    /**
     * bytesToHex method
     */
    static final char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes)
    {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ )
        {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }


}
```

Comment: It's okay if your English isn't perfect, but please take some time to make your question as clear as possible. Be consistent with your capitalization, and make sure that any acronyms are clear. Good luck!

Comment: One thing that isn't clear here is do you want this to be done automatically within your app, or when the app is closed? Notification you send from BLE, is that only the UUID? There are more questions to your question than answers. But, if you are looking for the solution within the app, then you should probably check occasionally for BT connection (not recommended), and if it's out of the app, then you're searching for a service to do this stuff for you in the background.